# ENV variable access on Heroku with Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, heroku

I have a PHP/Apache application deployed to Heroku. I want to enable basic auth on this when running on Heroku. This worked well...

```
AuthUserFile /app/prototypes/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
Require valid-user
```

However, I want to only enable this if PASSWORD_PROTECTED is set. I set a heroku config var like so:

```
heroku config:set PASSWORD_PROTECTED=true
```

and then updated .htaccess to look like:

```
<IfDefine %{ENV:PASSWORD_PROTECTED}>
    AuthUserFile /app/prototypes/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Access"
    Require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

But the Require valid-user never gets run, so I don't seem to be able to access ENV vars from .htacess in Heroku or I am doing this wrong. Any thoughts on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your syntax is a little off.

Rather than `<IfDefine>`, which [lets you test for variables set with `Define` or via the `-D` parameter on startup](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifdefine), you should use [the `<If>` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if). This was new in Apache 2.4, so examples are a little thin on the ground, but we can use those examples along with [this rather technical expression reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) to come up with this:

```
<If "-T reqenv('PASSWORD_PROTECTED')">
    AuthUserFile /app/prototypes/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Access"
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

[`reqenv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#functions) is a function that looks up an environment variable; [`-T`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#unnop) is an operator that returns true unless its argument is empty, 0, "false", "off", or "no".